# How to write efficient value comparer using EF 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following object:

```
public record Attachment
{
    public required string DocumentId { get; set; }
    public required DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
    public required string MimeType { get; set; }
    public string? Notes { get; set; }
}
```

I wrote this converter for a ScreenShot property which is of **Attachment** type:

```
  builder.Property(x => x.ScreenShot)
        .HasConversion(
        x => JsonSerializer.Serialize(x, JsonSerializerOptions.Default),
        x => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Attachment>(x, JsonSerializerOptions.Default)!,
        new ValueComparer<Attachment>(
                 (c1, c2) => JsonSerializer.Serialize(c1, JsonSerializerOptions.Default) == JsonSerializer.Serialize(c2, JsonSerializerOptions.Default),
                 c => JsonSerializer.Serialize(c, JsonSerializerOptions.Default).GetHashCode(),
                 c => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Attachment>(JsonSerializer.Serialize(c, JsonSerializerOptions.Default), JsonSerializerOptions.Default)!));
```

Is the above converter correct and performant and how to write it in another more performant way without needing the serialization logic?

Comment: Have you tested if this actually results in any perfromance problems?

Comment: Yeah, it involves serialization and deserialization operations which cause some performance issues.

Comment: The value comparer looks highly inefficient, but correct (assuming JSON serialization is idempotent)

Comment: @Charlieface serialization cannot be idempotent, because it's not an endomorphic operation, i.e. `serialize(serialize(x)) = serialize(x)` makes no sense. Maybe you mean reversible, i.e. `x = deserialize(serialize(x))`?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Idempotent meaning if you do it multiple times on the original value you get the same result.

Comment: @Charlieface why would that ever not be the case? Presuming the same serializer is used with the same settings.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Think of order of properties. In the Model it's clear but in serialized string, "id" property may be before "name" property or the other way round which would result in "not equal" if you then compared based on the result of serialization.

Comment: @Fildor wouldn't that imply that the serializer behaves non-deterministically?

Comment: Yes, which I _think_ it doesn't - but I would have to look that up to be 100% sure. I wouldn't count on it, though. @GoodNightNerdPride At least with some corner cases, there seem to be issues: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/76008 (not quite the same as here, but same ballpark)

Answer (score 3):

Using serialization is a quick-and-dirty approach for such case which should be working correctly but can have perfromance implications. More performant way would be to implement corresponding equality members (i.e. `Equals` and `GetHashCode`) and cloning manually.

If `DocumentType` is a type which correctly implements `Equals` and `GetHashcode` since `Attachment` is actually a [`record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) you can leverage the compiler generated equality and copy members for it:

```
.HasConversion(
    x => JsonSerializer.Serialize(x, JsonSerializerOptions.Default),
    x => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Attachment>(x, JsonSerializerOptions.Default)!,
    new ValueComparer<Attachment>(
        (c1, c2) => c1 == c2,
        c => c.GetHashCode(),
        c => c.CloneForExpression())
);
```

```
public record Attachment
{
    // needed because with can't be used in expressions ATM
    public Attachment CloneForExpression() => this with { };

    // ...
}
```

Which should be more effective than serializing data back and forth (though in theory it is more brittle or even straightforward erroneous depending on what type the `DocumentType` actually is due to the shallow copying, see the [Nondestructive mutation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#nondestructive-mutation) section of record docs). If shallow copying here is wrong then you will need to update (and possibly rename to `DeepClone`) the `CloneForExpression` method accordingly.